# malloc memory for pthread and then fork + execvp

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads, exec, fork

I get an event and based on that event i do some processing and then fork + execvp some other program (called some_jazzy_program). Initially i used a while loop where i did the following:

```
 while (some condition)
 {
      pid = fork();

      if (pid == 0)
      {
            do_some_work()

            execvp (some_jazzy_program..);
      }
      else 
      {
            do_some_bookkeeping();
      }
 }
```

The problem with this design is that if do_some_work() takes up large amount of time then i am not able spawn new processes fast enough to launch some_jazzy_program. To fix this, i started using pthreads:

```
  pthread_t *work_threads[MAX_FORKS_ALLOWED];

  while (some condition)
  {
      work_threads[index] = (pthread_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_t));

      pthread_create(work_threads[index], NULL, do_some_good_work, NULL);

      index ++;
  }

  void * do_some_good_work (void *arg)
  {
      pid = fork();

      if (pid == 0)
      {
            do_some_work()

            execvp (some_jazzy_program..);
      }
      else 
      {
            do_some_bookkeeping();
      }
 }
```

This design works. However, i have a few questions.

The fork + excvp is called which spawns a new process. Where should i call pthread_exit() in the parent program. With whatever i have read, i dont necessarily need to call pthread_exit since the thread automatically dies when the work its set out to do completes. In this context as soon as i do a fork + execvp it would die.

My other concern is about the work_threads[index] = (pthread_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_t)) -- the memory malloc that i am doing. When i use malloc i allocate memory from the heap. Where can i free this memory and release it back to the heap. Not doing anything looks like a memory leak to me.

Is what i am attempting here usually done -- first run multiple pthreads and within each pthread do a fork + execvp

Comment: Regarding the second problem, with you allocating memory, why simply *not* allocate memory and just have a plain array?

Comment: Also, having multiple threads that each does a `fork` is not very common I would think. At least not if the child-processes are running longer than the threads.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I dont want to use a plain array since i may end up doing 30-40 forks under some scenarios. I didnt want to allocate such a high memory in the stack. Are you suggesting that i can never free malloc'd memory here?

Comment: `sizeof(pthread_t)` is not very much, you would need several hundred thousands, if not millions, to fill up the stack.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean when you say the child-processes run longer than the thread. If i do a fork + execvp (some_other_program) then it should not matter how long the thread runs, right? As far as i am concerned, the thread dies only when the function do_some_good_work finishes. But, by then, i would have already forked + execvp'ed. Do you see any issues with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first problem, you need not call `pthread_exit`. If your main program want to keep track of the threads, you may use `pthread_join` and check the return status of the threads.

Regarding your second problem, you can avoid heap memory allocation by just using:
 `pthread_t work_threads[MAX_FORKS_ALLOWED];`

Regarding your third question, as Joachim said, it is not common to `fork` inside a thread; in fact a little dangerous too. [Think before you mix them](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linuxprogrammingblog.com%2Fthreads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them&ei=wgsYVLzzGsaiugTJqIGAAQ&usg=AFQjCNFBNWGXzl2rJSmxJ07mEXP0hVCnDw)